# Importing package only once in the main file

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a package that has the following structure (from cookie cutter).

[image]

In my src folder I have also a main.py file that runs a pipeline calling many functions placed in make_dataset.py, build_features.py....

So far in each of those files (make_dataset.py, build_features.py, predict_models.py), I am importing pandas (import pandas as pd) at the beginning of each file as pandas is needed in each of those files.

Is there any chance I can import pandas only once in the main.py? Or importing pandas in each file ((make_dataset.py, build_features.py, predict_models.py) is actually best practice even though it looks like I am importing 3 times the same library.

Comment: Python will only load the module once, even with multiple imports. Modules are singletons in Python. Don't worry about it, and import it in each file where it's needed.

Comment: Multiple imports do not reload the module - this is also important when testing in the same interactive session. ;)